# ImageMagick removes colors when alpha is 0 (png)

Tags: imagemagick

I am converting many 3D textures with imagemagick for a video game. My source files are png, my target files are png, too. But I notice that whenever the alpha channel drops to 0.0 my color information are gone (and I need them). I just want to scale all channels as they are. I guess there is a small switch that fixes that problem, but the deadline is near and I cannot find anything about that.

Simple command to reproduce this:
`convert source-with-alpha.png -scale 2014 target.png` (I also tried `-resize` and it also didn't work).

Doing just `convert source-with-alpha.png target.png` works fine though (but has no scaledown).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post links to example input and output images, so we can see what the issue might be. Perhaps you need to upgrade libpng or imagemagick or both. What versions are you using? `convert -version` will tell you your ImageMagick version and `convert -list format` will show you the PNG version on the right side of the PNG line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess ImageMagick is trying to optimise something but not sure what/why. Maybe the idea is that if something is transparent you can't see it, so we might as well make it black so it compresses well.

Anyway, try separating the channels so they are all just treated as independent channels, then resizing and recombining:

```
convert input.png -channel RGBA -separate -resize XxY -combine result.png
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I thought about something like that but I'm quite new to imagemagick and I thought it would be much more complicated. This solution works fine and I will accept this answer as soon as the system lets me do this. Again Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your problem. I have no issue resizing a transparent PNG image with ImageMagick 6.9.10.28 Q16 Mac OSX with libpng 1.6.36. Perhaps you need to upgrade one or both.

Image:
[image]

Make white into transparent:

```
convert logo.png -transparent white logot.png
```

[image]

Resize it:

```
convert logot.png -resize 25% logot_small.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried Mark Setchell answer with two different versions of Windows imagemagick but I still have this issue.
RGB becomes 0 if alpha is 0 when resizing.
A workaround was to add alpha a little bit so it becomes non-zero:

```
magic.exe input.tga -channel a -evaluate add 0.2% -channel RGBA -separate -filter Quadratic -resize -resize XxY! -combine result.tga
```

or also (same result)

```
magick.exe ( input.tga -alpha off -filter Quadratic -resize XxY! ) ( input.tga -filter Quadratic -resize XxY! -alpha extract -evaluate add 0.2% )  -compose Copy_Alpha -composite result.tga
```

("-filter Quadratic" is optional)

Answer (score 0):

Post one of your tga files so we can test with it. What is your ImageMagick version? There should be no need for any switch. This works fine for me on IM 6.9.10.65 Q16 Mac OSX.

Make a transparent TGA:

```
convert logo: -transparent white logo.tga
```

[transparent tga image](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/tga_test/logo.tga)

Resize by 50%

```
convert logo.tga -resize 50% logo2.tga
```

[resized transparent tga image](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/tga_test/logo2.tga)

Comment: You need an input texture that has a RGB value (non 0) but alpha 0 to test it.  The RGB value becomes 0.  Tested with ImageMagick-7.0.8-66-portable-Q16-x64. Sent you a sample by email